# how to get image from another project in the same solution with Src asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've two project in the same solution. I am trying to pick up an image from folder in project1 to project 2 in cshtml file. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: please share some code and what you have try, how you want to get it, what error do you get etc...

Answer (score 0):

Jlidi,

If you are trying to reference an image from another project you won't be able to directly reference any source outside your current project, you will need to import the image from the other project into your existing.

Unless this has to be separate I would just recommend making a copy of the image and placing it in both projects, you can perform an import on the image from an existing project but it will essentially just create a copy in your (RESX) Resource file in your existing project.